# OpenGL resource alocation

Tags: linux, opengl

How are GPU resources (memory, computing time) allocated to OpenGL contexts? There is possible to have multiple OpenGL applications/contexts running concurrently, for example OpenGL window manager with windowed OpenGL application, so there must be some mechanism to handle resource usage concurrency. Are there any commands that can be used to get OpenGL resource allocation information in similar fashion as "ps" works for system resources? Are there any commnands similar to "nice"?